# Windows scheduler that runs every x minutes daily on the command line

Tags: windows, command-line, scheduled-tasks, cmd.exe, windows-task-scheduler

Is there a way to schedule a task (.bat) through the command line that runs every five minutes daily?

I also want it to run even if the user isn't logged on. What is the exact command line syntax?

Answer (score 5):

#### Is there a way to schedule a task that runs every 5 minutes daily?

You can do this with the following command:

> schtasks /create /tn "MyTask" /sc minute /mo 5 /tr "MyTask.cmd"

Explanation:

- `/create` - create a new scheduled task
- `/tn "MyTask"` - give the task as name
- `/sc minute` - schedule the task with a frequency in minutes
- `/mo 5` - and modify the freqency to be every **5** minutes
- `/tr "MyTask.cmd"` - run the command `MyTask.cmd`

Source [schtasks](http://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html) - Create / edit a Scheduled Job/Task.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [schtasks](http://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html) - Create / edit a Scheduled Job/Task. The job can be created on the local or a remote computer.

Comment: Yes, but when i make this task, the moment i reboot my pc, the task scheduled isn't working anymore

Comment: It might be failng because you are not logged in immediately after a reboot. Is there anything in the event logs? Try using the `/RU username /RP password` options.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `schtasks.exe` - is part of the OS. Here are a lot of [examples by microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744.aspx). Here is the [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: The GUI for task administration is started by "taskschd.msc" for Windows 7 Enterprise. It might not be available for all Windows variants.

Comment: Isn't he asking for the command line version?

Comment: @boboes No, it's about launching a batch file once every 5 minutes.

Comment: The GUI is at least helpful to check what you have scheduled by other means. It also shows the available parameters to configure a task. But "schtasks /?" should also be a good start.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use the following:

```
SchTasks /Create /SC MINUTE /MO 5 /SD 12/31/9999 /TN "My Task" /TR %~dp0%~n0%~x0 /ST 23:59:59
```

as [DavidPostill](https://superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill) said:

```
/create - create a new scheduled task
/tn "My Task" - give the task as name
/sc minute - schedule the task with a frequency in minutes
/mo 5 - and modify the frequency to be every 5 minutes
/sd 12/31/9999 - date in which should begin the task mm/dd/yyyy
/st 23:59:59 - start date in which is going to start the task in 24 hour format
/tr "MyTask.cmd" - run the command MyTask.cmd
```

in my case for "/tr" I used the following:

```
%~dp0 - path (location) of the current file
%~n0 - current file name
%~x0 - extension of the current file
```

all information has gotten from the documentation about [schtasks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/schtasks), any other command you can check on [Windows commands](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands)